# How is dependency injection working?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am reading the Pro Spring 2.5 book and I have a question to how dependency injection works.

I understand the BeanFactory and doing dependency lookups. Now I read about dependency injection and I have some questions. Based on what I understand you want to limit the lookups to the minimum such as looking up an object for boot strapping the application. Then dependency injection will take care of the rest. However I don't understand this works.

Let say you have a beanfactory, you get an MyApplication instance that starts the whole application. The rest of the objects use dependency injection to get their collaborators. The beanfactory maintains the list of beans it manages but isn't this factory only available in the main method of the application? And if the beanfactory also manages the scope of their containing beans  I don't understand how that is done. Are the beanfactory global in some way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bean factory instantiates all objects. It parses your configuration (xml or annotations), instantiates your beans and sets their dependencies. Then all these beans are stored in the application context.

You usually have an entry point to your application - there you do `context.getBean(..)`. Now that bean has its dependencies injected, because it is put in the context by the bean factory.

The rule of thumb that will probably clear things: you never use the `new` operator (with bean classes) when using a DI framework. The framework makes the instances, not you.

Comment: So the bean that "starts" the application now have a register where it can get beans that are injected with their dependencies and ready for use?

Comment: yes. In a web context, for example the context (registry) is started by a listener, which is provided by spring and you don't see.

Answer (score 2):

So, there are two ways this can happen (as of Spring 3). In "traditional" dependency injection, the bean factory can only inject dependencies into beans it creates itself. In this scenario, the bean factory will resolve and inject all dependencies of a bean when that bean is first created.

The other way requires you to employ "full" AspectJ with either load- or compile-time weaving. In this scenario, you use an aspect in the spring-aspects.jar that basically pointcuts all `new` operations, allowing you to get dependency injection in arbitrarily created objects. This is triggered by using the `@Configurable` annotation. You can read more [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable).

Answer (score 0):

The whole point on inversion of control and dependency injection is that you (typically) *don't need* the beanfactory except to get your application started. Your dependencies "automatically appear" in your objects. This is basically intended for objects with very few, typically one, instance during the whole lifetime of your application.

E.g. if your MyApplication depends on an instance of MyModuleA, you can simply have it @Autowired. When you fetch the application object from beanfactory at start time it already comes with an instance of MyModuleA preset.

About the scopes: this comes from web context. Besides objects with only one instance ever you can have objects scoped to a user's session. There you can store information you need to keep over several requests but separate for different users, think: shopping cart.

Typically treat the bean factory as global. I think it would be possible to have several instances, but they would be disconnected and can't inject objects only known to other instances.